# How to fix a recursive hcf function?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make an HCF function in javascript using recursive functions as given in the code below. But somehow this only works for exact multiples of numbers (like 2,4 ; 52,104 etc). Co-prime numbers also gives 'undefined'. Please help me fix the bug.

I have tried substituting a local scope variable c = a % b. But this doesn't work out either.

The code:

```js
function hcf(a, b) {
    if (b == 1){
        return 1;
    } else if (a % b == 0){
        return b;
    } else {
        hcf(a,a % b);
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
hcf(4,2);
hcf(108,52);
hcf(9,4);
```

Expected Outcomes:

```
2
4
1
```

Actual Outcomes:

```
2 [Correct]
undefined [Incorrect]
undefined [Incorrect]
```

Comment: HCF = Highest Common Factor?

Comment: The `else` block lacks a `return`.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive case needs a `return` statement.